# Nifi obtain filename from csv column value

Tags: apache-nifi

I am reading from a database and making a csv out of it using **QueryDatabaseRecord** and **ConvertRecord** processors.

I want one of the columns in the csv to be extracted and used to name my CSV file that will be stored locally on my system via PutFile or in S3.

CSV looks like,

```
cola,colb,colc,date
A1,123,vin9,2020-02-04
A2,456,vin9,2020-02-04
A3,789,vin9,2020-02-04
```

I want to extract just the first row's *colc* and *date* field to produce a filename called **vin9-2020-02-04**.csv for my output dump.

Which processor can help me achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do that using **`ExecuteStreamCommand + UpdateAttribute`** Processor!

**`Flows:`**

> ***`Option1:`***
>
> **1.QueryDatabaseRecord**
>
> **2.ConvertRecord**
>
> **3.ExecuteStreamCommand**

[image]

`Sample Shell Script:`

This script gets file content and get only **`second line`** into **`attr`** attribute to the flowfile.

```
$ cat second_line.sh
#!/bin/sh
cat $1 |head -2|tail -1
```

> **4.UpdateAttribute:**

Add new property:

`filename`

`${attr:replaceAll('.+?,.+?,(.*)','$1'):replace(',','-')}.csv`

[image]

Output flowfile from `Updateattribute` processor will have the desired **filename**.

[image]

> ***`Option2:`***

Another way would be using **`Extract Text`** processor:

Add new property as:

`attr`

`^.*\r?\n(.*)`

once we get `attr` value as *second line* data then use **UpdateAttribute** processor to change the filename.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you guaranteed from the query to have the date column be the same value all the time? In either case, you can use PartitionRecord and partition on the `date` column, you will get flow file(s) out that each have all the records for a unique date. If you choose `basename` as the name of the user-defined property with value `/date`, each flow file will have the `basename` attribute set to the value of the date column. Then you can use UpdateAttribute to set `filename` equal to `${basename}.csv`.

Comment: Matty, thanks. What if I want to combine two fields in one? Like vin and date? Is that possible too?

Comment: You can partition on multiple columns, if you need to combine them into a single attribute you can use UpdateAttribute downstream and refer to each of the partition attributes in NiFi Expression Language to create a compound key